# C# Extension List<T> for one of DateTime property

Tags: c#, list, extension-methods

I have a website with filter options, when clients posts requests I do the check if filter property has value and if does.. do the filtering job:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ContentTable(ContentTableViewModel vm)
{
    vm = vm == null ? new ContentTableViewModel() : vm;
    var qList = _service.Get(); //IQueryable

    if (vm.From.HasValue)
        qList = qList.Where(x => x.Date >= vm.From.Value);
    if(vm.PlanTo.HasValue)
    {
        vm.PlanTo = vm.To.Value.AddDays(1);
        qList = qList.Where(x => x.Date < vm.To.Value);
    }
    vm.List = await qList.ToListAsync();
    return View(vm);
}
```

I use this quite often and that's why I would like to make extension method for List with "From" and "To" as method parameters and return filtered list. **important** is to also tell extension method which property will be filtered - in this case **Date**

```
public static void WhereBetweenDates<T>(this IList<T> list, DateTime from, DateTime to) 
{
     //? list has no property
}
```

Do I need to have BaseClass for each T ? To tell method "where T: Base" ?

Comment: What's wrong with `list.Where(x => x.DateTimeProp >= from && x.DateTimeProp < to)`? Why do you need an extension method for that?

Comment: Usually if user selects for instance dates From: 01.01.2020 and To: 02.01.2020 he wants to see results from TWO days... 01 and 02 of january... not just 01.. DateTime is also nullable DateTime? - usefull to display results if From is 01.01.2020 and To is null... list will contain matches from beginning of year

Comment: My point is that tou don't need another extension method on `List<>` since `Where` already provides the functionality you want. If you want to, you can create an extension method that takes in your own type (or interface) that has the `DateTime` property to search for and return a `bool` if the value of that property falls within the range of `from` and `to` - and than use this method in list's `Where` extension method, or if you want a list back you can use that in List's `FindAll` method - but in any case this shouldn't be (and actually can't be) an extension method on the list itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would pass lambda extracting date for T like this:

```
public static void WhereBetweenDates<T>(this IList<T> list, DateTime from, DateTime to, Func<T, DateTime> extractor) 
{
     foreach (var element in list)
     {
         var elementDt = extractor(element);

         if (elementDt > from && elementDt < to)
         {
             // accept element
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: How are `to` and `from` parameters are used here?

Comment: It would be fantastic if this could work: 
            `public static IQueryable<T> WhereBetweenDates<T>(this IQueryable<T> list, Func<T, DateTime> extractor, DateTime? from, DateTime? to ) 
        { 
            if(from.HasValue) 
                list = list.Where(x => extractor(x) >= from.Value);
             
            if(to.HasValue)
            {
                to = to.Value.AddDays(1);
                list = list.Where(x => extractor(x) < to.Value);
            }
            return list;
        }`